# C++ & Boost: I'm trying to find an example TCP program with a server that accepts connections from multiple clients

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, network-programming, client-server

A chat program would be a good enough example.
Just need a server that can accept multiple connections from the clients, and the server needs to be able to send messages to individual clients.

I plan to turn this into a distributed computing program to work with multiple Neural Networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is the Boost library that handles networking. There's a chat server example listed [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you an example progam. But to write a server things that you have to do:
1. server will listen at a port for connection
2. thread pool which will accept the connection and serve request
3. write the server code in thread safe manner

You have to use socket programming A good link for that http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/
you can use win32 api in windows and  [posix](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) for linux

Comment: I know the basics, I know I need to use sockets. Just... not with boost. =\

Comment: I have edited the post, u dont have to use boost if you dont want to.